# How to add regression line on scatter chart with Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, plot, regression

I have two datasets:

- for scatter I have X and Y values for selected period (lots of them),
- for regression line I have data for first and last point.

Is it possible to show this two series in the same chart?

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried so far, and what were your specific problems were.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this the method here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/04/11/reporting-services-recipes-book-downloads.aspx

Download the one on Linear regression.

You have to calculate the regression points from the data at the query level.

This helped me when doing something similar.